# Android bitmap don't see black (astgmatic ? )

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

I have a `bitmap`, containing only one black pixel.
I take the `bitmap` file and double-loop (like a matrix) control the color of each pixel. if it is black (Constant Value: -16777216 (0xff000000)), put them in an `array` of `integers`, the value 1, otherwise 0

The problem is that Android blurs the image apparently. because the 8 pixels around the black pixel, even if they are white, they see them as other than white (I do not know exactly what color) and the central pixel, does not see it as black, but another color .. then to all intents and purposes is astigmatism ... ideas on how to fix? I have to count the pixels blacks in a picture ...

place the code I use

```
 public int[][] DisegnaImpronta(Bitmap immagine) {

            int[][] matrice;

            matrice = new int[immagine.getWidth()][immagine.getHeight()];

            for(int i = 0; i <immagine.getWidth() ; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < immagine.getHeight() ; j++) {

                            int colore = immagine.getPixel(i, j);

                            /* bianco se il valore è 1, nero se il valore è 0 */
                            if(colore!=-1)System.out.println("coordinate: "+ i + " " + j + " c: " +colore); //qui mi notifica quando il colore è diverso da bianco

                            if(colore==-16777216){
                                    System.out.println("Un punto nero...");
                                    matrice[i][j]=1;

                            }else{
                                    matrice[i][j]=0;
                            }

                    }
            }
```

Sorry for the english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` clause is empty: `else {}`

This means your code always executes the line `matrix [i] [j] = 0;`. So you set all your pixels to 0.